# Проблема шрифтов на mac os mojave

Tags: html, веб-программирование, macos, шрифты, safari

Использую Грузинский шрифт. Раньше все было в порядке. Сейчас местами вместо букв квадратики. Проблема только в сафари 12. Вот ссылка на страницу [КЛИК](https://kawebs.com/db/projects/bella/)
Шрифт BPG Mrgvlovani 2010. Подключен через @font-face.
Шрифт работает только местами. Например в верхнем меню все ок, а вот в боковом одни квадратики,хотя шрифт везде один
вот скрин:
[image: Проблема]
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все решил проблему. Все дело было в text-transform: uppercase; удалил их все и все наладилось